# PHP cURL script adding a 'space' at end of filename

Tags: php, jquery

I'm calling a PHP script via AJAX that saves a remote image locally (via Mapbox API). Everything works great, except for the `result` includes a 'space' (`filename.jpg[space]`) at the end of the string.

Javascript:

```
var mapboxUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/v4/motioncrafter.96d11990/' + longitude + ',' + latitude + ',11/1280x720@2x.jpg80?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibW90aW9uY3JhZnRlciIsImEiOiJjaWg2dHJvM2YwNndudjJrdGI2amUzdnlyIn0.oN201-rjUC4DHhz7QhGJRA';
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../php/map.php",
        data: {
          map: mapboxUrl,
            },
        success: function(result) {
          $('.video_map').val(result);
        }
      });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$mapboxUrl = $_POST["map"];
$path = "../images/user-maps/";
$imageFile = $path . "map_wide_" . rand(10000, 99999) . time() . ".jpg";
$ch = curl_init($mapboxUrl);
$fp = fopen($imageFile, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

echo $imageFile;
?>
```

Any idea why this space is showing up?

Comment: I don't know why it's adding a space but you could always trim() it

Comment: Are you sure there is a space? It does not appear that your code would add a space there. Add this in the success call `console.log(result.match(/\s$/));`. Do you get `false` in the console?

Comment: My guess is that there's a space after `?>`. Everything after `?>` gets echoed to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this line:

```
?>
```

I suspect you have a space after that. Everything outside `<?php ... ?>` gets sent to the client, so if it's actually `?><space>`, the space will be appended to the image filename.

There's no need to have `?>` at the end of a script, the end of the file automatically tells PHP to stop processing the code.